# Repeat last value of a column, when it is empty -SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

Can we repeat last value of a column in SSRS? As in attachment, all blank rows in 
the last column should be filled with the latest value 702

[image]

I used Previous, Last functions but nothing helped

Comment: Can you show what you tried?

Comment: IIF(ISNOTHING(CSTR(Fields!R_Pax.Value))
 ,IIF(IsNothing(Previous(max(Fields!R_Pax.Value)))
  ,Last(Fields!R_Pax.Value)
  ,Previous(max(Fields!R_Pax.Value)))
 ,max(Sum(Fields!R_Pax.Value)))

Comment: I assume this is a matrix with column group on year?

Comment: all the values that you are seeing are the totals

Comment: That still doesn't answer the question. Is this a matrix or table?

Comment: I used Table not matrix

Comment: Does `Fields!R_Pax.Value` contain nulls or empty strings when there is no value?

Comment: Is this a table in sql server?  Can you post DDL and inserts or create a sql fiddle please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do it at SQL end and fetch data to SSRS

Steps:

1. Do pivot if needed
2. Get the data at granularity column. Here it is Absolute Month
3. Then use the SQL method to replcae the Nulls/ last values which are empty with the last highest value
   Ref:

   ```
   `select a.AbsoluteMonth,Mon
   ,first_value(a.S1_pax)over(partition by a.v1_p order by num ) as S_Pax
   ,first_value(a.S2_pax)over(partition by a.v2_p order by num ) as S2_Pax`
   from
   (select *
   ,sum(case when S1_pax is null then 0 else 1 end) over (order by num) as v1_p 
   ,sum(case when S2_pax is null then 0 else 1 end) over (order by num) as v2_p
    from X_Table
   )a
   ```

And fill all places respectively. Plz refer below output

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That's achievable if you do this:

**Step 1**. For your source, you build a sql query where you group the data by Year, AbsoluteMonth, etc.

So for each Year / AbsoluteMonth pair the report has only **ONE** value.

**Step 2**. Use below formula:

```
=IIf(IsNothing(Sum(Fields!Amt.Value)), Last(Fields!Amt.Value, "Year"), Sum(Fields!Amt.Value))
```

Here "Year" is group name, and Amt - your field name, which is probably R_Pax

**Step3**. (optional) Sort the data if it's not naturally sorted to provide the correct last value.

Step 1 is very important. Otherwise the cell with empty value will not show the last **total**, it will show the last value for a month, so if month (1) has values 30, 50, 60, and month (2) doesn't have any values, then it will show 60 for month(2), month(3), etc..., not sum(30+50+60).

Comment: This will not repeat, I already tried using Last function as I mentioned in question

Comment: @koushikveldanda your mentioned usage of Last function wasn't correct, that's why it failed. I created a brand new report and it works if implemented correctly!

Answer (score 1):

You better insert the remaining blank records with last value into your dataset before pass the data to report.
I assume your table is matrix.

```
DECLARE @Today DATETIME
SET @Today = GETDATE()

DECLARE @MatrixData TABLE (
  Month1 INT
, Year1 INT
, Value INT
)

INSERT INTO @MatrixData (Month1, Year1, Value)
SELECT MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, Id * -1, @Today)) AS Date1Month, YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, Id * -1, @Today)) AS Date1Year, Id * 10 AS Value1
FROM (
    SELECT TOP 60 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Id) AS Id
    FROM SysObjects
) A
ORDER BY Date1Year, Date1Month

SELECT * FROM @MatrixData

-- Insert blank month of last year with last value
INSERT INTO @MatrixData (Month1, Year1, Value)
SELECT A.RunningMonth, A1.MaxYear, A1.LastValue
FROM (
    SELECT TOP 12 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Id) AS RunningMonth
    FROM SysObjects
) A
INNER JOIN (
    -- Get Last Value in @MatrixData 
    SELECT A.MinMonth, A.MaxMonth, A.MaxYear, A1.Value AS LastValue
    FROM (
        -- Get Max Month Last Year in @MatrixData 
        SELECT MAX(A1.Month1) AS MinMonth, A.MaxMonth, A.MaxYear
        FROM (
            -- Get Max Month & Max Year
            SELECT MAX(Month1) AS MaxMonth, MAX(Year1) AS MaxYear
            FROM @MatrixData
        ) A
        INNER JOIN @MatrixData A1 ON A.MaxYear = A1.Year1
        GROUP BY A.MaxMonth, A.MaxYear
    ) A
    INNER JOIN @MatrixData A1 ON A.MinMonth = A1.Month1 AND A.MaxYear = A1.Year1
) A1 ON A.RunningMonth > A1.MinMonth AND A.RunningMonth <= A1.MaxMonth

SELECT * FROM @MatrixData
```

Comment: Nope its a table

Comment: Either matrix or simple table, the script describe how to insert remaining month with last value.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle it is done like this. SQL Server has both COALESCE and LAG functions. So this must be possible with SQL Server also. There is also another stackoverflow question similar to this. Just could not locate it.

```
create table mytab(n number, m number);
insert into mytab values(1,null);
insert into mytab values(2,null);
insert into mytab values(3,44949);
insert into mytab values(4,null);
insert into mytab values(5,null);
insert into mytab values(6,null);
insert into mytab values(7,null);
insert into mytab values(8,null);
insert into mytab values(9,null);
insert into mytab values(10,null);
insert into mytab values(11,74631);
insert into mytab values(12,null);
insert into mytab values(13,null);
select t.*, coalesce(m, lag(m ignore nulls) over (order by n))
from mytab t;
```